# Comparing current usernames to new usernames, and checking there are no case insensitive duplicates (Python3)

Tags: python-3.6

The goal is to compare a list of current users, to a list of current users, and check if there are no duplicate names. If there is a 'John', 'JOHN" should not be accepted, so it should be case insensitive.

This is what I have so far, it works, but it is assuming that `current_users` is already in lowercase.

```py
current_users = ['samantha', 'albert', 'amanda', 'dick', 'becky', 'alfonso']

new_users = ['AMANDA', 'juan', 'albert', 'alexandra', 'sara', 'raheem']

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user.lower() in current_users:
        print("Sorry! This username is taken!")
    else:
        print("You are welcome to use this name!")
```

My question is: What is the cleanest way to convert all the elements in `current_users` into lowercase, without having to rewrite the whole list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
current_users = ['samantha', 'albert', 'amanda', 'dick', 'becky', 'alfonso']

new_users = ['AMANDA', 'juan', 'albert', 'alexandra', 'sara', 'raheem']

val = {True:'Sorry! This username is taken!',
       False:'You are welcome to use this name!'}

arr = [val[True] if new_user.lower() in current_users 
       else val[False] for new_user in new_users ]

print '\n'.join(arr)
```

Output:

```
Sorry! This username is taken!
You are welcome to use this name!
Sorry! This username is taken!
You are welcome to use this name!
You are welcome to use this name!
You are welcome to use this name!
```

Using list comprehension and dictionary can be useful.